# How do I invoke my program with the -r option from within Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, random

In this project for my C program I am requested to invoke it with `-r` (see below), but I am not sure how to do this in Xcode. Where is this done?

“ ...because the program uses a fixed seed — invoke it with `-r` if you want different output each time"

I presume the requirement is to use the `-r` as a command line argument. Am I right? This is my assumption.

This is what I have done....

**Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme**

- Step 1 - Info tab

  - Select Arguments Passed on Launch
  - For Executable, navigate to the Terminal app
  - Uncheck Debug executable
- Step 2 - Arguments tab

  - Add the following into the Arguments Passed On Launch field:

    ```
    ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME} -->
    ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${CoinToss1}

    -r
    ```

But doing the above has not made any difference.

The `-r` option has not had any effect doing it this way, because it is still using the same seed and producing identical output for the coin tosses.

Project guidelines here:
http://www.pcg-random.org/using-pcg-c-basic.html

Comment: Presumably, you're required to modify your program so that the signature of `main()` is `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or equivalent, and then you need to check whether the `-r` argument was passed to your program, and if it was, you need to do something different to make sure the sequence of random numbers generated is different (call `srand()`?).  Since you've not shown your program code it is hard to know whether you're on the right track or not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: This is source code already given to them with `main` declared `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.

Comment: Why are you adding “${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME} -->”, “${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${CoinToss1}”, an empty string, and “-r” to the arguments instead of just adding “-r”? When I add just “-r”, the code runs and shows varying data from run to run.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — people on SO should not have to go look at the off-site instructions to know what they've been given to work with.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I was able to determine from text in the question that OP had been given existing source code to work with: “… because the program uses a fixed seed…”

Comment: Thanks to all for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @EricPostpischil already mentioned in the comments just adding `-r` should work:

- Edit Scheme
- on the left choose 'Run'
- use 'Arguments' tab
- add in 'Arguments Passed on Launch' the `-r`

It should look like this:

[image: scheme]

As a test you can use a simple main:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    if(argc == 2) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This would output `-r` in this case.

Comment: This is working (using the -r option alone). I mislead myself into believing that I needed to also use Terminal, but this works correctly inside Xcode as it is. It seeds nicely. Thank you.